# Comparing two list of objects in Python

Tags: python, list, object, compare

I have class Host, which has properties ip and ports

```
class Host:
    def __init__(self, ip):
        self.ip = ip
        self.ports = []
```

I have two lists of objects: `old_hosts` and `new_hosts`. Now I want to compare these lists and found new host or only host with new opened ports. Does exists some special function in python, which could compare these lists?

E.g.

```
old_hosts:
[0] ip: 192.168.1.1, ports: 53,80
[1] ip: 192.168.1.2, ports: 53,80
[2] ip: 192.168.1.3, ports: 53,80

new_hosts:
[0] ip: 192.168.1.1, ports: 53,80
[1] ip: 192.168.1.2, ports: 53,80,443
[2] ip: 192.168.1.3, ports: 53,80
[3] ip: 192.168.1.4, ports: 53,80
```

And I would like to get something like this

```
New discovered host 192.168.1.4
New discovered port 443 on host 192.168.1.2
```

I have solved this problem by three nested for loops, but I don't like this solution. I think there is exists some better way how to do it.

Comment: Can you give some sample lists and expected answers? That would be great :)

Comment: @Vikash I have edited my post. I hope, it will be understandably.

Comment: @rumcajs your data does not look like lists

Comment: Are the objects strings or what?

Comment: @TalhaTayyab and what is it? I think it is list of objects

Comment: @user19077881 yeah, everything is string

Comment: You could compare the Lists using `set(new_hosts).difference(set(old_hosts))` but it then still  2 loops to separate a new IP from a new Port.